# ESS: Turn off [TRUNCATED] in ESS R session

Tags: ess, r

I'm running some code in a .Rmd file using M-n v u, but when I do so, my output is truncated.  I'd like to turn this feature off, but the only documentation I can find mentioning truncation is for `ess-eldoc-abbreviation-style` and it's related to the mini-buffer.

Here's an example of what happens.
Code

```
while(my.round <= max.round){

input.restart.file <- paste0(output.dir,"Restart/rstart.round.", my.round - 1, ".rst")
output.restart.file <- paste0(output.dir,"Restart/rstart.round.", my.round, ".rst")

    
if(my.round==1){ #initial set up
    ## Initialize parameter object
    ## Set initial phi value
    parameter <-
        initializeParameterObject(
        genome = genome,
        model = which.model,
        sphi = init_sphi,
        mutation.prior.mean = mutation.prior.mean,
        mutation.prior.sd = mutation.prior.sd, ## should try changing this
        num.mixtures = 1,
        gene.assignment = rep(1, genome.length),
        split.serine = TRUE,
        mixture.definition = mixDef)
    divergence.iteration <- initial.divergence
.
.
.
```

R Window in Emacs

```
+ while(my.round <= max.round){
+ 
+     input.restart.file <- paste0(output.dir,"Restart/rstart.round.", my.round - 1, ".rst")
+     output.restart.file <- paste0(output.dir,"Restart/rstart.round.", my.round, ".rst")
+ 
+     
+ if(my.round==1){ #initial set up
+     ## Initialize parameter object.... [TRUNCATED]
```

UPDATE: I've now downloaded a copy of the emacs source code and searched for "[TRUNCATED]" and get nothing.

I've also searched my .emacs folders and get the same results.

For what it's worth, I'm running

1. Ubuntu-Mate 20.04
2. GNU Emacs 26.3

- (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14) of 2020-03-26, modified by Debian

3. ESS version 18.10.2

Comment: This option is likely from R, not from Emacs. Are you using knitr? It can be configured to do this.

Comment: OMG!  Thanks for pointing out this obvious alternative explanation!  I am using knitr, but can't find any direct documentation on this.  This posting about the Tinn-R console https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292384 suggests it is related to a `source()` command option `max.deparse.length`.  I will investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like I need to figure out how to modify the options ESS sends to R using `.ess.source()` and `.ess.eval()`.  Specifically, I need to change the argument

```
max.deparse.length: integer; is used only if ‘echo’ is ‘TRUE’ and gives
      the maximal number of characters output for the deparse of a
      single expression.
```

I can do this including the following in the source file I'm working with.

```
library(default)
default(.ess.source) <- list(max.deparse.length=1E5)
default(.ess.eval) <- list(max.deparse.length=1E5)
```

(NB: it doesn't work in my `.Rprofile` because R doesn't know about these libraries until they are some how loaded by emacs-ESS.)

Comment: It looks like I want to set `max.depare.lengt = echo()` rather than an integer. The relevant code seems to be in: `ess/etc/ESSR/R/.basic.R:` Specifically,  `.ess.eval <- function(string, visibly = TRUE, output = FALSE,
                      max.deparse.length = 300,
                      file = tempfile("ESS"), local = NULL) {`  and   `.ess.source <- function(file, visibly = TRUE, output = FALSE,
                        max.deparse.length = 300, local = NULL,
                        fake.source = FALSE, keep.source = TRUE,
                        message.prefix = "") {`